# primereact file upload uploadHandler change status of uplaod

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I'm using Primereact's file upload component with customUpload prop and Uploadhandler callback. I want to change the status of the uploaded file when my uploadHandler function finishes executing.

```
<FileUpload className={`w-full`} name="demo[]" customUpload={true} uploadHandler={async (e) =>{
} }.... />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but you must be using PrimeReact 9.6.0 which was released today.  just make sure you get a `ref` to your FileUpload.

```xml
<FileUpload ref={ref} ...
```

Then with that ref you can update the list of uploaded files like..

```js
const yourFiles = []; // array of your already uloaded files
ref.current.setUploadedFiles(yourFiles);
```